# Page listing all categories for CPT

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom post type called "services" with a category called "service_areas" and want to be able to pull up a page listing all of the "service_areas". I'm not exactly sure what this page would be called, because I believe that a "category archive page" would be a page listing all of the posts from a *specific* one of the "service_areas"s.

Calling the url `domain-name.com/service_areas/a_service_category` pulls up a category archive page for the `a_service_category` category as expected.

What is a good way to make `domain-name.com/service_areas` pull up a page listing all of the "service_areas" (as opposed to a 404)?

More Details:

The custom post type is `services` and it's custom taxonomy is `services_category` with a slug of `service_areas`:

```
/*
 * Create Services CPT
 */
function services_post_type() {

// Set UI labels for Custom Post Type
    $labels = array(
        'name'                => _x( 'Services', 'Post Type General Name', 'total' ),
        'singular_name'       => _x( 'Service', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'total' ),
        'menu_name'           => __( 'Services', 'total' ),
        'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Service', 'total' ),
        'all_items'           => __( 'All Services', 'total' ),
        'view_item'           => __( 'View Service', 'total' ),
        'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Service', 'total' ),
        'add_new'             => __( 'Add New', 'total' ),
        'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Service', 'total' ),
        'update_item'         => __( 'Update Service', 'total' ),
        'search_items'        => __( 'Search Service', 'total' ),
        'not_found'           => __( 'Not Found', 'total' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'total' ),
    );


    $args = array(
        'label'               => __( 'services', 'total' ),
        'description'         => __( 'Services we offer', 'total' ),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'revisions' ),
        'hierarchical'        => true,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-businessman',
        'menu_position'       => 20,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'services' ),
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'post',
    );

    // Registering your Custom Post Type
    register_post_type( 'services', $args );

}



/**
 * Register Caregiver category.
 *
 */
function register_categories() {

    // Define and sanitize options
    $name = __( 'Service Categories', 'total' );
    $slug = 'service_areas';

$args = array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => $name,
        'singular_name' => $name,
        'menu_name' => $name,
        'search_items' => __( 'Search','total' ),
        'popular_items' => __( 'Popular', 'total' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'All', 'total' ),
        'parent_item' => __( 'Parent', 'total' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent', 'total' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit', 'total' ),
        'update_item' => __( 'Update', 'total' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New', 'total' ),
        'new_item_name' => __( 'New', 'total' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate with commas', 'total' ),
        'add_or_remove_items' => __( 'Add or remove', 'total' ),
        'choose_from_most_used' => __( 'Choose from the most used', 'total' ),
    ),
    'public' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_tagcloud' => true,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => $slug, 'with_front' => false ),
    'query_var' => true
);

    register_taxonomy( 'services_category', array( 'services' ), $args );

}

add_action( 'init', 'services_post_type', 0 );
add_action( 'init', 'register_categories', 0 );
```

==================

I noticed that if I filter 'pre_get_posts', `$query->query['name'] == 'service_areas'` is true for that url. Possibly I could load a custom template based on that test and loop through `get_terms( 'service_areas' )`, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: @MaxYudin Yes. I also have `category-service_areas.php`. I think this theme might be preventing the templates from loading, but wouldn't that require the url to be `category/service_areas` so that WP know's we want a category archive page?

Comment: Is `service_areas` a custom taxonomy?

Comment: yes it is. i will update the answer with a couple of details...

Comment: Post the full code of your custom taxonomy definition

Comment: @belinus i believe that's all of it. It's actually done by public static methods in a class, but I don't imagine that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a page in the admin panel called service areas and create a rewrite rule that tells wp to load a corresponding **page-service-areas.php** template.

```
function add_rewrite_rules () {
    add_rewrite_rule( '^service_areas/?$', 'index.php?pagename=service-areas', 'top' );
}
add_action('init', 'add_rewrite_rules');
```

Then in page-service-areas.php build out the query you want.

The following link helps you visualize how wordpress determines what page template to load:

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

UPDATE:

1. Add the above function (to themes `functions.php` or
   elsewhere).
2. Flush rewrite rules by saving "settings ->
   permalinks"
3. In the admin panel, create a blank page called
   "Service Areas".
4. Create a file in the theme with the content
   you want to load. (copy of page.php, archive.php or some other loop
   or content).

Now you should be able to click on the link for the page you created in admin (`yoursite.com/service-areas`) OR—thanks to our rewrite rule—(`yoursite.com/service_areas`) and see your template page.

Comment: Not implementing so far. I have changed permalink settings to Plain and created a document in the main theme directory named `page-service-areas.php` and flushed rewrite rules (which I imagine wouldn't matter for plain permalink settings). When the url is `domain-name.com/?pagename=service-areas`, it still comes up as a 404. Have tried this with custom theme as well as `twentythirteen`.

Comment: haven't tested the code out but in theory what you're telling wordpress is that when a user lands on domain.com/service_areas/, load the page-service-areas.php template

Comment: also, it's important that you create an actual page with service_areas as it's slug for this to work

Comment: What do you mean by "actual page with service_areas as it's slug"? That's something different than the `page-service-areas.php` template?

Comment: In the admin panel, under pages, create a new page called Service Areas and edit it's slug so that it's service_areas instead of service-areas.

Comment: there might be some type of issue with the slug and the template having underscores as opposed to dashes. play around with that.

Comment: Do seem to be making some headway. With page slug and template and rewrite_rule all using hyphen, it loads the `page-service-area.php` template.

Comment: This seems to work. Will edit your answer...

Comment: Yeah, it will definitely load the template even without the rewrite rule because wordpress will, by default, look for a template called page-*pagename*.php for a page with slug *pagename*, the rewrite rule was to force wordpress to skip loading the service_areas archive page and load the page with it's template instead... not sure how to make it work in your particular case though but i guess you figured it out?